# issue connecting puppet master

Tags: network-programming, puppet, agent

When I run this command `sudo puppet agent --test`, I get this message

`Error: Could not request certificate: Error 500 on SERVER:`

On the [main] section of the `puppet.conf` file, I put `server=puppet`, and then in my `/etc/hosts` file, I put `10.XX.XX.X puppet` entry. Even, if I put the plain `DNS` of the master in the `puppet.conf`, and add the ip `10.XX.XX.X my_plain_master_DNS`, I still get the same error. If I run `puppet agent --test --server my_plain_master_DNS`, I still get the same error. How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it, in fact there was an issue with my master not starting because of an `Address already in use` problem. After checking some docs; I found that it may come from `apache` binding the `8140` port, preventing `puppet` to use it. So I stopped the `apache` server, started the `puppet` master and then started again apache, and it worked !